# How to remove a specific character within a column in r?

Tags: r, string, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have a dataset of IDs:

```
VARIANT_ID
01_1254436_A_G_1
02_2254436_A_G_1 
03_3255436_A_G_1 
10_10344745_A_G_1 
11_11256437_A_G_1 
11_11343426_A_G_1 
12_12222431_A_G_1
14_14200436_A_G_1 
15_15256789_A_G_1
```

I am looking to remove the 0 from only the beginning characters of the  rows with IDs starting with 01-09, but I'm having trouble doing this without removing other 0s further in the column, and only see similar questions for other languages.The output I want is:

```
VARIANT_ID
1_1254436_A_G_1
2_2254436_A_G_1 
3_3255436_A_G_1 
10_10344745_A_G_1 
11_11256437_A_G_1 
11_11343426_A_G_1 
12_12222431_A_G_1
14_14200436_A_G_1 
15_15256789_A_G_1
```

Only the zeros at the start of each row have been removed, how do I specify this? I'm from a biology background so any help would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
structure(list(VARIANT_ID = c("01_1254436_A_G_1", "02_2254436_A_G_1", 
"03_3255436_A_G_1", "10_10344745_A_G_1", "11_11256437_A_G_1", 
"11_11343426_A_G_1", "12_12222431_A_G_1", "14_14200436_A_G_1", 
"15_15256789_A_G_1")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `gsub` function. Use a ^ to indicate the start of the string so that you don't remove 0s elsewhere.

```r
x$VARIANT_ID <- gsub("^0", "", x$VARIANT_ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

optional solution with `tidyverse`

```
df$VARIANT_ID <- str_remove(df$VARIANT_ID, pattern = "^0")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a `tidyverse` solution

```r
ggg$new_variant <- stringr::str_replace(ggg$VARIANT_ID, "^0", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` as well

```
df1$VARIANT_ID <- sub("^0", "", df1$VARIANT_ID)
```